# Can we convert selenium scripts into json files and automate this task?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver, build-automation

I want to know if multiple selenium scripts can be converted into json files respectively, using a Java engine if we create it? And if yes is it worth working on the engine?
The purpose is to convert those json files into feature files.